# Как правильно привязаться к бд в WPF

Tags: wpf, .net, entity-framework, mvvm

Изучил несколько примеров из сети и столкнулся с непониманием.
Если нам нужно отобразить данные из бд в `DataGrid`, то обычно, как я понял, создается коллекция `ObservableCollection<T>` и уже в нее загружаются данные через метод `ToList()`, далее эта коллекция связывается с View.
А если нам нужно добавить какую-то строку в базу и сразу же отобразить эти изменения в `DataGrid`, то добавление происходит сначала в `ObservableCollection<T>`, а потом в бд, т.е. операция добавления проходит два раза. Если ли какой-то грамотный способ привязаться к бд с использованиеи Entity Framework и иметь возможность обновлять ее содержимое? И почему нельзя напрямую взаимодействовать с бд минуя VM и `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много. Самый простой: используйте EntityFramework. У DbSet объекта есть свойство [Local](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.local?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.DbSet%601.Local);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0) которое является ObservableCollection. Все изменения в этой коллекции сохраняются напрямую в базу данных.